# My training score is ~99% but my test score is ~50%. Why is my test score so low?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am building a decision tree classification model. My data has 11 features + 1 target column (12 columns in total). I performed a train test split (70% training, 30% testing), used a z-score transformation on my x_train (x-mean/standard deviation). And when I built my model, my training accuracy is 0.995 and my testing accuracy is 0.501.

At first I was confused why there was such a big gap. I researched online and they say to do a split before transformations (which was what I did).

I created a copy and tried splitting AFTER transforming. I know thats wrong but it brought my scores closer together.

I also read that it may be due to overfitting. But I split my test into 70% which I don't think counts as overfitting.

Here are my codes:

```
X.head().to_dict()
```

```
{'col1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'col2': {0: 50, 1: 37, 2: 29, 3: 47, 4: 18},
 'col3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'col4': {0: 57, 1: 38, 2: 27, 3: 51, 4: 1},
 'col5': {0: 7, 1: 26, 2: 18, 3: 7, 4: 14},
 'col6': {0: 0, 1: 7, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3},
 'col7': {0: 7, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 4, 4: 0},
 'col8': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'col9': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'col10': {0: 142, 1: 465, 2: 679, 3: 916, 4: 195},
 'col11': {0: 21, 1: 23, 2: 27, 3: 5, 4: 1}}
```

```
y.head().to_dict()
```

```
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1}
```

my train test split

```
# Separate into training (70%) and testing (30%) sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape
```

my z-score transformer

```
# Create a function to load data
def transform_data(data):
    
    # Find mean of data
    mean=data.mean()
    
    # Find standard deviation of data
    sd=data.std()
    
    # Transform the data using a Z-score transformation
    data_tf = (data-mean)/sd
    
    # Returns dataset
    return data_tf

# Transform the train dataset
X_tf = transform_data(X_train)
```

my decision tree classifier

```
# Create improved model
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth = None, min_samples_leaf=4, 
                             min_samples_split=10, splitter='best', random_state = 0)

# Fit the model
dtc.fit(X_tf,y_train)

# Create function to print model accuracy scores
def print_accuracy(model, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    
    # Get train and test accuracy scores
    train_acc = model.score(x_train, y_train)
    test_acc = model.score(x_test, y_test)
    
    # Print score
    print(f'Training accuracy: {train_acc}')
    print(f'Testing accuracy: {test_acc}')

# Accuracy score
print_accuracy(dtc, X_tf, y_train, X_test, y_test)
```

Is there a way to improve my test scores? Any suggestions much appreciated. Cheers!

**EDIT 1**

My dtc hyperparameters are like that because I used GridSearchCV to find the best hyperparams.

**EDIT 2**

Could my test score be bad because I didnt transform them?

Comment: Try shuffling the data before partition into test and train buckets. It could be the case (highly unlikely) that the bottom 30% of the data is not in line with the top 70% data. To confirm this, please shuffle the data before splitting and see what accuracy you get after shuffling, If the accuracy is still skewed like 90% and 50% then either you have very few data points to train this model, or the model is getting more inclined towards the training data and not learning a generalized view from the data, try adjusting the hyper-parameters in this case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried shuffling using X = X.sample(frac=1, random_state=0).reset_index(drop=True) but the scores have minimal changes

Comment: In your code you are transforming the train dataset, but where are you transforming your test dataset?

Comment: "But I split my test into 70% which I don't think counts as overfitting." This has nothing to do with overfitting, your model is overfitting if you did everything else right. Also the test set and any new samples need to have the same transformations applied as the training set.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the pred function in your codes, so I assume you did everything right in there.

You probably should look at your data more carefully. You can try checking out exact look of your tree by using visualization techniques, e.g. [Display via graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621190/display-this-decision-tree-with-graphviz)

> I also read that it may be due to overfitting. But I split my test into 70% which I don't think counts as overfitting.

It does count as overfitting if you get your train score way higher than your test. To get rid of it you may need to find more data, or manage to use **K-fold cross-validation** technique for your data.

Also, how did you find out these model hyper-parameters? You can try to tune your model using GridsearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV. [Hyper-parameter optimizers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection)

It would be nice to see your final data representation, after the normalization.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion you can do followings.

first thing is you need to understand data or distribution.

1. Tune the decision tree with max_depth and try with gini-index
2. Use cross-validation for testing the model insted of train-test
3. You can change a algorithm with extra-tree algorithm like
   random-forest,gradient-boosting.

tuning decisiion tree :- [reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-tune-a-decision-tree-f03721801680#:%7E:text=The%20best%20way%20to%20tune,samples%20belong%20to%20one%20class.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried using cross_val_score for my test data and I got like ~98%. Why is it so different than the accuracy score?
cross_val_score(dtc, X_test, y_test, cv=10)